# Blazor [WASM] Get image size

Tags: blazor, webassembly

Expecting the answer to be using jsInterop but never hurts to ask.

Can the following be done in Blazor:

```
const img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
```

As seen here:[How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this done with `SixLabors.ImageSharp` nuget on Blazor Wasm.

```
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var data = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(ImageUrl);
    using(var img = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(data))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{img.Height}");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it worth the additional assembly. Probably the JS interop is better for this.